# How do I draw a coordinate system with grid lines and markings?

Tags: tikz-pgf, draw

I wish to draw a coordinate system in LaTeX (using `tikz`) and I have not been able to find a good instruction. I know how to draw basic graphics, but surely there must be a better way, than to draw the axes manually?
My goal is to have a coordinate system  with grid lines and markings on the axes.

Comment: like this ? `\documentclass[tikz,border=5mm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[gray!50] (-1,-1) grid (4,4);
\draw[->] (-1,0)--(4,0) node[below left]{$x$};
\draw[->] (0,-1)--(0,4) node[below left]{$y$};
\draw[blue,thick,-stealth] 
(0,0)--(1,0) node[midway,below]{$\vec{i}$};
\draw[red,thick,-stealth] 
(0,0)--(0,1) node[midway,left]{$\vec{j}$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}`

Comment: you should look for `pgfplots`, the package  based on `tikz` and dedicated for drawing 2-D and 3-D diagrams with many options for drawing axis grids, labeling them etc.

Comment: Thank you; the code you provided helped!

Comment: Is there a way to put matkings (1,2,3,...) on the axes?

Comment: @Zarko I am not trying to plot a graph or a funtion, but rather to illustrate the addition of complex numbers.

Comment: Even this is simple to draw in `pgfplots` :-)